# Odoo v12 javascript double rpc call problem

Tags: javascript, odoo, rpc

I have created the class crm.dashboard.py have 2 methods, I want to call them in JS, the first controller works but when I call the second I get this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'crm.dashboard' has no attribute 'get_test_info'
```

Any solution please?

```
init: function(parent, context) {
    this._super(parent, context);
    var crm_data = [];
    var test_data = [];

    var self = this;
    if (context.tag == 'crm_dashboard.dashboard') {
        self._rpc({
            model: 'crm.dashboard',
            method: 'get_crm_info',
        }, []).then(function(result){
            self.crm_data = result[0]
        })

        self._rpc({
            model: 'crm.dashboard',
            method: 'get_test_info',
        }, []).then(function(result){
            self.test_data = result[0]
        })


        .done(function(){
            self.render();
            self.href = window.location.href;
        });


    }
}
```

Code of the method:

```
@api.model
def get_test_info(self):

    expected_revenue = 0
    obj_test = self.env['sale.order'].sudo().search([])
    amount_total = 0
    for sale in obj_test:
        amount_total = round(amount_total + (sale.amount_untaxed + sale.amount_tax))
    test_details = [{}]
    if test_details:
        data = {
            'amount_total': amount_total,

        }

        test_details[0].update(data)

        print("TEST________________", test_details)
    return test_details
```

Comment: The module who contain the python code is installed ?

Answer (score 0):

The message says "I don't find the method get_test_info in model crm.dashboard".

The problem isn't your JS but "your" python file.

Possible error:

- The python file with model 'crm.dashboard' and method 'get_test_info' isn't import in `__init__.py`
- The folder models isn't import in your `__init__.py` of your module.
- Missing depends (implied not installed)
- The method name is different.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer but i have checked the python file, it has no problem

Comment: Could you update your first message with your py file containing the method get_test_info ?